# Как включить в Битрикс24 раздел «Группы и проекты» на AWS?

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

Как включить в Битрикс24 раздел "Группы и проекты" /workgroups/ Коробка на AWS установлена и не работает этот раздел? Кто с таким сталкивался подскажете пожалуйста почему так? Поиск не дал ответа.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]